# Slide dynamic text on hovering a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am breaking my head to get the div content to slide before appearing when I hover over the relevant item that is suppose to change the content of the div dynamically using jquery. The content just changes but I would like them to slide, I have tried various things but in vain.

Please excuse me if my question is silly, I am new to Jquery.

HTML

```
<div class="servdescripitems">
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        <p>Paragraph of first service</p>
        <ul>
        <li>Heading 1 list 1</li>
        <li>Heading 1 list 2</li>
        </ul>
    <div class="button">Service 1</div>
</div>

<ul class="serviceslist">
  <li class="service1"></li>
  <li class="service2"></li>
  <li class="service3"></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$('.service1').mouseover(function() {
  $('.servdescripitems').html('<h3>Heading 1</h3><p>Paragraph of first service</p><ul><li>Heading 1 list 1</li><li>Heading 1 list 2</li></ul><div class="button">Service 1</div>');
});

$('.service2').mouseover(function() {
  $('.servdescripitems').html('<h3>Heading 2</h3><p>Paragraph of second service</p><ul><li>Heading 2 list 1</li><li>Heading 2 list 2</li></ul><div class="button">Service 2</div>');
});

$('.service3').mouseover(function() {
  $('.servdescripitems').html('<h3>Heading 3</h3><p>Paragraph of second service</p><ul><li>Heading 3 list 1</li><li>Heading 3 list 2</li></ul><div class="button">Service 3</div>');
});
```

CSS

```
.servdescripitems {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.servdescripitems h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: #ed1f24;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.servdescripitems p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.servdescripitems ul{
    list-style-image: url("../images/servicelist.png");
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.servdescripitems li {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}




.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
   background: #3b363b;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7e7e7e), to(#3b363b));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7e7e7e, #3b363b);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7e7e7e, #3b363b);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7e7e7e, #3b363b);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7e7e7e, #3b363b);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   font-size: 11pt;     
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   width: 150px;
   height: 20px;
   margin: 5px auto;
}
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #ed1f22;
   background: #ed1f22;
   color: #ffffff;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #ed1f22;
   background: #ed1f22;
   }

.serviceslist {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.serviceslist li {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.service1 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/service1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-position: 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 2px solid #ed1f24;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.service2 {
    height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 2px solid #ed1f24;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.service3 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 2px solid #ed1f24;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

I have fiddled the script [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alfredhd/emmn1m9t/)

Comment: What do you mean by 'slide'? Where should the content slide from and to?

Comment: Basically would like the first content to disappear by sliding to the left or the right and the next content to slide from the other direction.

Comment: The fiddle is in the bottom of the post, anyways it's here https://jsfiddle.net/alfredhd/emmn1m9t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jQuery the simplest slides are Up and Down as they are built-in.

I've added a div inside your current service details container, so the container's size is not affected when sliding content in/out

This is how I've updated each of your mouseover functions:

```
$('.service1').mouseover (function() {
    //check if current service shown is not the same - this avoids sliding to same content
    if(inside_div.attr("current-service")!="1"){
    //slideUp current content
    inside_div.slideUp(function(){
        //once slideUp is finished, change the content of the inside div...
            inside_div.html('<h3>Heading 1</h3><p>Paragraph of first service</p><ul><li>Heading 1 list 1</li><li>Heading 1 list 2</li></ul><div class="button">Service 1</div>');
      // ... then tell the div what service content it now has, and slide it back down
      inside_div.attr("current-service","1").slideDown();
        });
  }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g66aa0oo/

Let me know if any further explanation is needed.

Also See: https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

If you really want left/right sliding, I'd recommend looking at a carousel effect plug-in such as [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: Thanks so much Colby, it works like a charm, I wasn't particular about sliding left or right as I just wanted to kick that boring content change. Thanks again, much appreciated!